# Only draw bottom of SVG donut chart

Tags: javascript, angular, svg

I am trying to only show half of the piechart. The segments, when in view, should always start at angle 0. I'm not sure how to explain it better, but here's a Stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vmk6f8

Try to imagine cutting the chart in half horizontally. So at the start, the green part should "drain", and the red part should slowly appear.

I've tried a couple things to no avail. I'm getting stuck with the math behind this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<svg height="200" width="400" viewBox="0 80 160 80" class="donut-chart">...</svg>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vzenha)

Comment: That's a solution. Thanks!